# Symfony2 form : how to get the submited value in the url?

Tags: php, symfony, routes

what I need is "onSubmit" to get the "query" value, and put it in the "_search_all" route, normally this would look like => `{{ path('_search_all', {'slug': query_val} ) }}` this way I can get a route like this in my browser `localhost/search-all/symfony2`

**The current form**

```
    <form class="searchbar" method="POST" action="{{ path('_search_all') }}">
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Search"/>
        <span>
         <input type="text" name="query" required/>
        </span>
    </form>
```

Solutions so far:

1. `method="GET"` however this will create the "ugly" looking url
2. use the `friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle`

any inputs are welcome

Comment: Do you want to get the "query" input value by javascript or do you want to get the value in your controller? I could not understand what you mean

Comment: I want to press submit and this will make my browser go to `/search/<keyword>` this is the pattern from the `_search_all` route, I couldn't find anywhere how to get the form do this, I can do it without the keyword ( just /search/ ) but I want it with the keyword

Comment: check my below answer hopefully will help you

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `onSubmit` event and set a javascript variable which contains the path; as sample try something like:

```
var frm_action = "{{ path('_search_all', {'keyword' : ''}) }}";
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#myForm').attr('action', frm_action + $('input[name="query"]').val());
});
```

and your need to add the ID to your form:

```
<form class="searchbar" method="POST" id="myForm" action="" >
```

Comment: this is what I thought doing,using the jsrouting-bundle is easier, but I hope there is something else ... will wait a little bit more